# Manage several almost identical client databases using Entity framework (or other ORM?)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, orm

I'm prototyping an ASP.NET Web API that needs to talk to several databases which are almost identical. Each of our customers have their own instance of our database structure, but some are specialized to integrate with other systems they have. So for example in one database the `Client` table might have the column `AbcID` to reference a table in another system, but other databases won't have this column. Other than that the two tables are identical in name and columns. The columns can also have different lengths, `varchar(50)` instead of `varchar(40)` for example. And in some databases there can be one extra table. I have focused on solving the different columns problem first.

I was hoping to use an ORM to handle the data access layer of the API, and right now I'm experimenting with Entity framework. I already solved how to dynamically connect to the different databases from an API-call, but right now they have to be completely identical in structure.

I have tried to set up double .edmx models with a Database-first approach but this causes conflicting class names between the models. So instead I tried Code-first and come up with this (which isn't working).

**DbContext extension:**
In the constructor I check which database is being accessed and if it is one of the special ones I flag it for the model configuration.

```
public partial class MK_DatabaseEntities : DbContext
{

    private string _dbType = "dbTypeDefault";
    public DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Resource> Resource { get; set; }

    public MK_DatabaseEntities(string _companycode)
        : base(GetConnectionString(_companycode))
    {
        if(_companycode == "Foo")
            this._dbType = "dbType1";
    }

    // Add model configurations
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Configurations
        .Add(new ClientConfiguration(_dbType))
        .Add(new ResourceConfiguration());
    }

    public static string GetConnectionString(string _companycode)
    {
        string _dbName = "MK_" + _companycode;

        // Start out by creating the SQL Server connection string
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder sqlBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();

        sqlBuilder.DataSource = Properties.Settings.Default.ServerName;
        sqlBuilder.UserID = Properties.Settings.Default.ServerUserName;
        sqlBuilder.Password = Properties.Settings.Default.ServerPassword;

        // The name of the database on the server
        sqlBuilder.InitialCatalog = _dbName;
        sqlBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = false;

        sqlBuilder.ApplicationName = "EntityFramework";
        sqlBuilder.MultipleActiveResultSets = true;

        string sbstr = sqlBuilder.ToString();
        return sbstr;
    }
}
```

**ClientConfiguration:**
In the configuration for `Client` I check the flag before mapping properties to database columns. *This however does not seem to work.*

```
public class ClientConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Client>
{
    public ClientConfiguration(string _dbType)
    {
        HasKey(k => k.Id);
        Property(p => p.Id)
        .HasColumnName("ID")
        .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        if (_dbType == "dbType1")
        {
            Property(p => p.AbcId).HasColumnName("AbcID");
        }
        Property(p => p.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");
        Property(p => p.LastName).HasColumnName("LastName");          
    }
}
```

**Client class:**
This is how my `Client` class looks like, nothing weird here.

```
public class Client : IIdentifiable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AbcId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public interface IIdentifiable
{
    int Id { get; }
}
```

Back-up solution is to use raw SQL queries to deal with the offending tables and ORM for the rest, but it would be awesome if there is some way to do this that I have not thought of. Right now I'm trying Entity framework, but I am not opposed to trying some other ORM if that one can do it better.

Comment: Can you have a factory that will generate the model configuration with different company code?

Comment: You mean like @JotaBe suggested below? Yes I suppose that might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Code First supports this scenario:

1) Common entities for both models:

```
public class Table1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

2) Base version of table 2

```
public class Table2A
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Name2 { get; set; }
    public Table1 Table1 { get; set; }
}
```

3) "Extended" version of table 2, inherits version A, and adds an extra column

```
public class Table2B : Table2A
{
    public int Fk { get; set; }
}
```

4) Base context, including only the common entities. Note that there is a constructor which accepts a connection string, so there is no parameterless constructor. This forces inheriting contexts to provide their particular connection string.

```
public class CommonDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CommonDbContext(string connectionString)
        :base(connectionString)
    {

    }

    public IDbSet<Table1> Tables1 { get; set; }
}
```

5) The context A, inherits the common context, adds the `Table2A`, and ignores the `Table2B`

```
public class DbContextA : CommonDbContext
{
    public DbContextA() : base("SimilarA") { } // connection for A
    public IDbSet<Table2A> Tables2A { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Ignore<Table2B>(); // Ignore Table B
    }
}
```

- The context B, inherits the common, and includes the `Table2B`

  public class DbContextB: CommonDbContext
  {
      public DbContextB() :base("SimilarB") { } // Connection for B
      public IDbSet Tables2B { get; set; }
  }

With this setup, you can instance either `DbContextA` or `DbContextB`. One advantage is that both inherit `CommonDbContext`, so you can use a variable of this base class to access the common entities, no matter if the concrete implementation is version A or B. You only need to change to the concrete type to access the specific entities of A or B (`Table2A` or `Table2B`in this sample).

You can use a factory, or DI or whatever to get the required context depending on the DB. For example this could be your factory implementation:

```
public class CommonDbContextFactory
{
    public static  CommonDbContext GetDbContext(string contextVersion)
    {
       switch (contextVersion)
       {
         case "A": 
             return new DbContextA();
         case "B":
             return new DbContextB();
         default:
             throw new ArgumentException("Missing DbContext", "contextVersion");
       }
    }
}
```

*NOTE: this is working sample code. You can of course adapt it to your particular case. I wanted to keep it simple to show how it works. For your case you'll probably need to change the factory implementation, and expose the connection string in A and B context constructors, and provide it in the factory method*

**Handling the different classes of your entities**

The easiest way to handle the different entities of each `DbContext` is to use polymorphism, and or generics.

If you use polymorphism you need to implement methods which use the type of the base class (as parameter and as return type). This parameters and vars will hold entities either of the base or of the derived class (`Table2A` or `Table2B`). In this case, each context will receive an entity of the right type, and it will work directly without trouble.

The problem is when your app is multilayered, uses services or is a web app. In this case when you use the base class the polymorphic behavior can be lost, and you'll need to handle the entities of the base class. (For example if you let the user edit an entity of derived class in a web app form, the form can only take care of the properties of the base class, and when it's posted back, the properties of the derived class will be lost) In this case, you need to handle it intelligently (see note below):

**For reading** purposes, if you have a `Table2B`, you have a direct casting to `Table2A`. You can implement functionality for `Table2A` and directly used it. I.e. you can return collections or individual values of the base class (in many cases implicit casting will be enough). No more worries.

**For inserting/updating**, you have to take extra steps, but it's not too difficult. You need to implement methods that receive/return `Table2A` parameters in your contexts, or in another layer, depending on your architecture. For example, you can make the base context abstract and define virtual methods for this. (See example below). Then you need to make the right implementation for each particular case.

- if you receive a `Table2A` but need to insert it in `Table2B`, simply map entity A into entity B with `AutoMapper` or `ValueInjecter` and fill the remaining properties with default values (beware of `AutoMapper` and EF dynamic proxies: it won't work).
- if you receive a `Table2A` and need to update a `Table2B`, simply read the existing entity from the DB and repeat the mapping procedure (`ValueInjecter` will be less troublesome than `AutoMapper` also for this case).

This is a very simple example of what can be done, but you need to adapt it to your particular case:

Inside  `CommonDbContext` class, declare virtual methods for the base type, like this:

```
public virtual Table2A GetTable2AById(int id);
public virtual void InsertTable2A(Table2A table);
```

You can also use generic interfaces/ methods, instead of abstract class / virtual methods, like this:

```
public T GetTable2AById<T>(int id)
{
   // The implementation
}
```

In this case you should add the necessary constraints to the `T` type, like `where T: Table2A` or the ones you need (`class` `new()`).

*NOTE* It's not exact to say that the polymorphism is lost in this cases, because you can really make polymorphic Web Services with WCF, or Web API, adapt your UI to the real class of your entity (with templates for each case) and so on. That depends on what you need or want to achieve.

Comment: This might work, it seems versatile enough for our situation, my only concern is that I might need to constantly check in every action if I'm supposed to use `Table2A` or `Table2B` in an add or return or whatever. But I suppose there's no helping that since they need to be different. I'll take this into consideration and test out.

Comment: This problem can be handled quite easyly. Read my updated answer: I've added extra info at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Been there, done that.

In all seriousness: dump EF in this specific case; it will bring a lot of pain and suffering for no benefit.

What you'll eventually end up doing (putting my Fortuneteller Hat on) is you'll rip out all the EF-based code, create an abstract object model and then write a series of backends that will map all the various database structures back and forth to said clean abstract object model. And you'll be either using raw SQL or something lightweight like Dapper or BLToolkit.

Comment: Interesting, I was afraid it'd have to come to something like that, do you have any good arguments for this I can use to convince my colleagues of the idea of not using an ORM? ;) I'll do some research into how to do something like that cleanly/maintainable, I've been coding in PHP lately so my C# is rusty.

Comment: I happened to look back on this post today and read your comment again. We ended up trying for EF since I couldn't convince my colleagues to use something else. But a few years down the line we began ripping out EF in favor of Dapper just as you predicted. We didn't need an abstract object model as you described, instead we managed to slowly consolidate and normalize all customer's databases so they were identical in structure eventually. I do wish I could have followed your advice and just wanted to let you know that you were right.